# How do you programmatically edit a property on an ABUnknownViewController after it has been pushed on the navigationController?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, abaddressbook

So, I have an ABRecordRef that I've defined all the necessary properties (name, number, address, image, etc).  This RecordRef has been added to a ABUnknownPersonViewController...then pushed to the stack.

```
   [[self navigationController] pushViewController:(ABUnknownPersonViewController*)controller animated:YES];
```

On a separate thread, I've downloaded updated information.  How do I (programmatically)modify the ABRecordRef of the person being displayed by the ABUnknownPersonViewController which has already been pushed to the stack?

In the docs, I don't see any getters/setters for the ViewController.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this was by updating other variables in the thread, then updating the ABRecordRef on the main thread.  ABRecordRef can't be updated on a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [NSNotificationCentre](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

You can use

```
- [NSNotificationCentre addObserver:selector:name:object:]
```

in your ABUnknownPersonViewController and

```
- [NSNotificationCentre postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]
```

where you have retrieved the data.

You can find me on [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io/francesco) if you need some guidance.